# non-destructive piping in vim?

Tags: unix, vim, vi

Is there a way to pipe selected text through an external command in vim, but not to replace the selected text with the output? Occasionally I want to copy something in a vim buffer to the X clipboard, so I use something like `%!xclip` -- but then I have to "undo" that command to get the text back since xclip doesn't return anything. Short of writing a wrapper script around xclip that also echoes the text back, is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you use gvim you can copy directly to the X clipboard with the special register `+`. `"+yy` copies current line to clipboard. You can also use visual selections.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `%!xclip` use

```
%w !xclip
```

Note the space between the `w` and the `!`. See

```
:help :w_c
```

Answer (score 1):

For copying to the clipboard, I use

```
"*y
```

For more on the difference between between `"*` and `"+`, you'll want to check out [`:h x11-selection`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/gui_x11.html#x11-selection). For me, the following seems to be relevant:

> Xterm, by default, always writes visible selections to both PRIMARY and
>   CUT_BUFFER0.  When it pastes, it uses PRIMARY if this is available, or else
>   falls back upon CUT_BUFFER0.  For this reason, when cutting and pasting
>   between Vim and an xterm, you should use the "* register.  Xterm doesn't use
>   CLIPBOARD, thus the "+ doesn't work with xterm.

So I'll be sticking with `"*` instead of `"+` that *peth* mentioned, but you might do well to test which ones works best for your usage pattern.

Comment: Yup, `*` register is closer to question as `xclip` uses the `PRIMARY` selection by default, too.